# How do I unmount a tmpfs that is missing from /etc/mtab?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, tmpfs

I have the following line in /etc/fstab:

```
none  /home/hydra/tmp  tmpfs  user,noauto,size=1000M,uid=1001,gid=1001  0  0
```

I can do `mount ~/tmp` as user hydra and it gets mounted ok. The only problem is that even thought it gets added to `/proc/mounts`, it does not get added to `/etc/mtab`. When I try a `umount ~/tmp` (again as hydra) it complains:

```
umount: /home/hydra/tmp is not mounted (according to mtab)
```

And when I try `-f` or `-n`, it complains that I am not root.

---

**Some more info on the system that manifests this problem:**

On `sudo umount /home/hydra/tmp`, the fs gets unmounted (I think I needed to used `-f` too)

- Debian version is `testing`
- `mount --version` -> `mount from util-linux 2.19.1 (with libblkid and selinux support)`
- `ls -l /etc/mtab` -> `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 921 Nov 14 09:08 /etc/mtab`
- `cat /proc/mounts | grep rootfs` -> `rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0`
- `/home`, `/home/hydra` nor `/home/hydra/tmp` are symbolic links

Comment: What happens when you run this as root?

Comment: i think you have columns switched around in /etc/fstab.  and what's the none for in the first column?

tmpfs /home/hydra/tmp user,noauto,size=1000M,uid=1001,gid=1001  0  0

that's how i normally see it

Comment: Oh and by the way, having an entry in `/etc/fstab` makes no difference to the `mount` command afaik? (i.e. it isn't required) If you wanted to mount a new addition to `/etc/fstab`, use `mount -a`

Comment: @matt No, vrinek's syntax is correct. The first column is the device name, it's ignored for non-device-backed filesystems such as `tmpfs`. vrinek: what version of Debian are you running? What version of the `mount` package? What does `ls -l /etc/mtab` show? Is `/` mounted read-only? Is `/home` or `/home/hydra` or `/home/hydra/tmp` a symbolic link (with that tmpfs unmounted, what does `readlink -f /home/hydra/tmp` show)?

Comment: @PriceChild An entry in `/etc/fstab` is required if you want to call `mount` as a non-root user.

Comment: Hint: Many distributions now choose to replace `/etc/mtab` with a symlink pointing to `/proc/self/mounts` to avoid such kinds of problems.

Comment: @Gilles (and @PriceChild) I added the info you requested on the question